# Using multiple SIMD (vectorization) at the same time

Tags: c, assembly, parallel-processing, intel, cpu-registers

I was inspired by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66521344/why-is-processing-an-unsorted-array-the-same-speed-as-processing-a-sorted-array/66521565#66521565) and wondering whether it's possible to use multiple SIMD instructions at the same time, since a CPU core may have multiple vector processing unit ([page 5 of this slides](https://www.alcf.anl.gov/files/HC27.25.710-Knights-Landing-Sodani-Intel.pdf)).

The code is:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    // Generate data
    const unsigned arraySize = 32768;
    int data[arraySize];

    for (unsigned c = 0; c < arraySize; ++c)
        data[c] = std::rand() % 256;

    long long sum = 0;

    for (unsigned i = 0; i < 100000; ++i)
    {
        // Primary loop
        for (unsigned c = 0; c < arraySize; ++c)
        {
            if (data[c] >= 128)
                sum += data[c];
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The assembly code compiled:
[compiled for AVX512](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:2,endLineNumber:36,positionColumn:2,positionLineNumber:36,selectionStartColumn:2,selectionStartLineNumber:36,startColumn:2,startLineNumber:36),source:%27%23include+%3Calgorithm%3E%0A%23include+%3Cctime%3E%0A%23include+%3Ciostream%3E%0A%0Aint+main()%0A%7B%0A++++//+Generate+data%0A++++const+unsigned+arraySize+%3D+32768%3B%0A++++int+data%5BarraySize%5D%3B%0A%0A++++for+(unsigned+c+%3D+0%3B+c+%3C+arraySize%3B+%2B%2Bc)%0A++++++++data%5Bc%5D+%3D+std::rand()+%25+256%3B%0A%0A++++//+!!!!!!+With+this,+the+next+loop+runs+faster.%0A++++//+std::sort(data,+data+%2B+arraySize)%3B%0A%0A++++//+Test%0A++++clock_t+start+%3D+clock()%3B%0A++++long+long+sum+%3D+0%3B%0A%0A++++for+(unsigned+i+%3D+0%3B+i+%3C+100000%3B+%2B%2Bi)%0A++++%7B%0A++++++++//+Primary+loop%0A++++++++for+(unsigned+c+%3D+0%3B+c+%3C+arraySize%3B+%2B%2Bc)%0A++++++++%7B%0A++++++++++++if+(data%5Bc%5D+%3E%3D+128)%0A++++++++++++++++sum+%2B%3D+data%5Bc%5D%3B%0A++++++++%7D%0A++++%7D%0A%0A++++double+elapsedTime+%3D+static_cast%3Cdouble%3E(clock()+-+start)+/+CLOCKS_PER_SEC%3B%0A%0A++++std::cout+%3C%3C+elapsedTime+%3C%3C+std::endl%3B%0A++++std::cout+%3C%3C+%22sum+%3D+%22+%3C%3C+sum+%3C%3C+std::endl%3B%0A++++return+0%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:55.695208169677926,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang1300,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%270%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%271%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-O3+-march%3Dknl%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1,tree:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+clang+13.0.0+(C%2B%2B,+Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,m:73.69267900241351,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:1,editor:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+clang+13.0.0+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:26.30732099758648,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:44.304791830322074,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4) and [compiled for AVX2](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:2,endLineNumber:36,positionColumn:2,positionLineNumber:36,selectionStartColumn:2,selectionStartLineNumber:36,startColumn:2,startLineNumber:36),source:%27%23include+%3Calgorithm%3E%0A%23include+%3Cctime%3E%0A%23include+%3Ciostream%3E%0A%0Aint+main()%0A%7B%0A++++//+Generate+data%0A++++const+unsigned+arraySize+%3D+32768%3B%0A++++int+data%5BarraySize%5D%3B%0A%0A++++for+(unsigned+c+%3D+0%3B+c+%3C+arraySize%3B+%2B%2Bc)%0A++++++++data%5Bc%5D+%3D+std::rand()+%25+256%3B%0A%0A++++//+!!!!!!+With+this,+the+next+loop+runs+faster.%0A++++//+std::sort(data,+data+%2B+arraySize)%3B%0A%0A++++//+Test%0A++++clock_t+start+%3D+clock()%3B%0A++++long+long+sum+%3D+0%3B%0A%0A++++for+(unsigned+i+%3D+0%3B+i+%3C+100000%3B+%2B%2Bi)%0A++++%7B%0A++++++++//+Primary+loop%0A++++++++for+(unsigned+c+%3D+0%3B+c+%3C+arraySize%3B+%2B%2Bc)%0A++++++++%7B%0A++++++++++++if+(data%5Bc%5D+%3E%3D+128)%0A++++++++++++++++sum+%2B%3D+data%5Bc%5D%3B%0A++++++++%7D%0A++++%7D%0A%0A++++double+elapsedTime+%3D+static_cast%3Cdouble%3E(clock()+-+start)+/+CLOCKS_PER_SEC%3B%0A%0A++++std::cout+%3C%3C+elapsedTime+%3C%3C+std::endl%3B%0A++++std::cout+%3C%3C+%22sum+%3D+%22+%3C%3C+sum+%3C%3C+std::endl%3B%0A++++return+0%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:55.695208169677926,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang1300,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%270%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%271%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-O3+-mavx2%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1,tree:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+clang+13.0.0+(C%2B%2B,+Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,m:73.69267900241351,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:1,editor:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+clang+13.0.0+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:26.30732099758648,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:44.304791830322074,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)

After inspecting the assembly code, I discovered that the inner loop (array traversal) was vectorized. In the case of AVX512 (-march=knl, knights landing), each step consists of processing 64 elements, by calling 8 SIMD instructions, each adding 8 elements to the previous result.

The intermediate result is stored in 4 `zmm` registers, each consisting of 8 elements. Finally 4 `zmm` registers will be reduced to a single result `sum`. It seems these SIMD instructions are called serially because it uses the same `zmm5` register to store intermediate variable.

a piece of assembly:

```
# 4 SIMD
vpmovzxdq       zmm5, ymm5    # extends 8 elements from int (32) to long long (64)          
vpaddq  zmm1, zmm1, zmm5      # add to the previous result

vpmovzxdq       zmm5, ymm6    # They are using the same zmm5 register           
vpaddq  zmm2, zmm2, zmm5      # so I think they are not parallelized

vpmovzxdq       zmm5, ymm7              
vpaddq  zmm3, zmm3, zmm5

vpmovzxdq       zmm5, ymm8              
vpaddq  zmm4, zmm4, zmm5

# intermediate result stored in zmm1~zmm4
# read additional 32 elements and repeat the above routine once
# in total 8 SIMD and 64 elements in each FOR step after compilation
```

My questions is, according to Intel, Knights Landing CPU have 2 vector processing units for each core ([page 5 of this slides](https://www.alcf.anl.gov/files/HC27.25.710-Knights-Landing-Sodani-Intel.pdf)). Therefore, would it be possible to do 2 AVX512 SIMD computation at the same time?

Comment: Even KNL does some small amount of register-renaming for vector regs, allowing these independent uses of the same architectural register to overlap.  The loop-carried dependencies use separate accumulator regs.  See [Why does mulss take only 3 cycles on Haswell, different from Agner's instruction tables? (Unrolling FP loops with multiple accumulators)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45113527) the top of my answer on re: reg renaming.

Comment: (And BTW, are you *actually* tuning for discontinued Xeon Phi compute cards?  Normally we'd use `-march=skylake-avx512` maybe with `-mprefer-vector-width=512` for modern servers, https://godbolt.org/z/nEbYGYxrr, or `-march=icelake-client`  )

Comment: Clang *does* have a silly missed optimization, though: it uses `vmovdqa32       zmm5 {k1} {z}, zmm5` to zero some elements according to the compare result, instead of zero-masking as part of the `vpmovzxdq`, or better merge-masking as part of the `vpaddq` (to give more ILP (instruction-level parallelism) by not using the compare result until after the zero-extension, so `vpcmeqd` and `vpmovzxdq` can run in parallel even for the same load result, maybe needing less loop unrolling).  Of course if the compiler knew the data was all <= 256, it wouldn't need to widen to avoid overflow.